# Generating JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I'm trying to parse the rows in a table that I generate using Javascript by adding items to a cart and then create a json object when the user hits save order of all the items and pass it to a php script using `$.post` in jQuery.

The only trouble I'm having is understanding JSON objects and how to push more items onto the object. I get an error in firebug telling me that `devices[i]` is undefined. Not really sure how else to accomplish this. I thought it was really just an array.

```
    function Save()
  {
    var devices = new Object();
    var i = 0;

$("#device_tbl tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
    var manufid = $(this).find("td").eq(0).find(".manuf_id").html();
    var modelid = $(this).find("td").eq(1).find(".model_id").html();
    var condition = $(this).find("td").eq(2).find("select").val();
    var carrier = $(this).find("td").eq(3).find("select").val();
    var imei = $(this).find("td").eq(4).find("input").val();
    var price = $(this).find("td").eq(5).html();
    alert(manufid+"\n"+modelid+"\n"+carrier+"\n"+imei+"\n"+price);

    devices[i].manufid = manufid;
    devices[i].modelid = modelid;
    devices[i].carrier = carrier;
    devices[i].imei = imei;
    devices[i].price = price;

    i++;

    });
document.write(devices);     //just for debugging


$("#final").show();  
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You currently have devices declared as an object, but you're treating it like an array.

You need to declare it as an array of objects.

```
  function Save()
  {
    var devices = new Array();
    var i = 0;

$("#device_tbl tr:gt(0)").each(function(){
        var manufid = $(this).find("td").eq(0).find(".manuf_id").html();
        var modelid = $(this).find("td").eq(1).find(".model_id").html();
        var condition = $(this).find("td").eq(2).find("select").val();
        var carrier = $(this).find("td").eq(3).find("select").val();
        var imei = $(this).find("td").eq(4).find("input").val();
        var price = $(this).find("td").eq(5).html();
        alert(manufid+"\n"+modelid+"\n"+carrier+"\n"+imei+"\n"+price);

        devices[i] = new Object();
        devices[i].manufid = manufid;
        devices[i].modelid = modelid;
        devices[i].carrier = carrier;
        devices[i].imei = imei;
        devices[i].price = price;

        i++;

        });
document.write(devices);         //just for debugging


$("#final").show();
}
```

or something like that.

(Updated to show it in your code)

Comment: The "devices[i] = new Object();" part is critical, declaring it as an array is optional